# DualShock 4 Bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04: only touchpad works

Tags: bluetooth, games, steam

When I connect it with *usb*, Steam detects it and it works as expected in Steam Big Picture.

When I connect it with *bluetooth*, only the touchpad works and acts as a mouse. If I then use ds4drv with xpad profile then Steam detects it as an XBOX 360 controller and I can play.

Is it possible to skip the ds4drv workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given here: [PS4 controller is not recognised by Steam - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027212/ps4-controller-is-not-recognised-by-steam-18-04)

It worked for me:

> sudo apt install steam-devices